# How to save search preferences to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a advanced search form and I wanted to know how can I save the user selections to the database. The current setup saves each search performed to the database, thus allowing me to have statistics of what users are searching for on the website.

The question I have is how can I save that users selections to their account so that it preloads when they return to the website, or they can create lists of saved search options. I have a social networking app so this would be helpful to the User so that they do not have to enter the age range, zip code, etc each time they visit the website.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Searches controller:

```
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    if @search.save
      redirect_to @search
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @users = @search.users
  end
```

Search model:

```
  def users
    @users ||= find_users
  end

    private

    def find_users
      users = User.order(:id)
      users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
      users = users.where(zip_code: zip_code) if zip_code.present?
      users = users.where(children: children) if children.present?
      users = users.where(religion: religion) if religion.present?
      users = users.where(ethnicity: ethnicity) if ethnicity.present?

      if min_age.present? && max_age.present?
        min = [ min_age, max_age ].min
        max = [ min_age, max_age ].max
        min_date = Date.today - min.years
        max_date = Date.today - max.years
        users = users.where("birthday BETWEEN ? AND ?", max_date, min_date)
        users
      end
      users
    end
  end
```

Search form:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :gender %><br />
  <%= f.select :gender, ['male', 'female'], :include_blank => true %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :zip_code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :zip_code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :children %><br />
    <%= f.select :children, [['Yes, they live with me'], ['I want kids now'], ["I want one someday"], ["Not for me"]], :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :religion %><br />
    <%= f.select :religion, [["Agnostic"], ["Atheist"], ["Christian"], ["Catholic"], ["Buddhist"], ["Hindu"], ["Jewish"], ["Muslim"], ["Spiritual without affiliation"], ["Other"], ["None"], ["Prefer not to say"]], :include_blank => true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ethnicity %><br />
    <%= f.select :ethnicity, [["Asian"], ["Biracial"], ["Indian"], ["Hispanic/Latin"], ["Middle Eastern"], ["Native American"], ["Pacific Islander"], ["White"], ["Other"]], :include_blank => true %>
  </div>    <%= f.select :min_age, (18..75), :include_blank => true %>
    to
    <%= f.select :max_age, (18..75), :include_blank => true %>


  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use json, marshal or any other serializers to serialize the search params as a string ,then store it into the cookie or database.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the search settings in the [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session). The drawback is that when a client visits the site from a different computer or browser, there are no saved search settings, because the session id is stored in a cookie.

If you really want the settings persisted in the database, you could create a `search_settings` field on the `User` model and serialize the settings to this field. If you are using Postgresql you could use the `array` or `hstore` column type.